# First time making pcb using photoresist...not sure if I am starting out right

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

Haven't pulled the trigger on my first attempt to make a pcb using the photo-resist method.  Here is my setup.

Created the board layout in Eagle (free version)
Purchased photo-resist from ebay - seems there is no information on the product I bought.
Purchased positive developer from MG Chemical

My first attempt seemed to indicate that the layout transparency needs to be a negative image (traces clear and background black)  Is there something I should have done to be able to use positive images?

I made a small exposure box using 180 UV LEDs and it seems to expose the film in about 10 minutes.

Is there a way to get Eagle to print negative images of the payout artwork?

What should I look for in photo-resist and developer if I want to develop from a positive image?

I've seen a few YouTube tutorials that show the exposed photo-resist being developed using sodium carbonate.  Is that better or not as good as using MG Chemical positive developer or did I miss understand them entirely?

Is there something I should be using instead?  Unfortunately there is so much info on YouTube and the web that is not consistent and hard to figure out who to listen too.

Comment: I'm not a MG Chemicals fanboy by any stretch, but their stuff *is* pretty damn good.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of selecting the layers you want printed from the "displayed layers" list of the editor and using the print tool to produce an image, use the CAM processor. Select the layers you want, and use PS_Inverted as the output "device", which will produce an inverted black and white postscript document.

[image]

You can render the postscript file with Acrobat, PS View, InfranView and others. The same applications should allow you to send it directly to a printer as well.

[image]

Comment: Since OP has an AskUbuntu account, I'd like to add that I've had great success using Inkscape for post-processing postscript output from Eagle. Useful if you want to print multiple boards, or add logos and such.

Comment: Jams:  I will play with that a little later today.  I know PS does a better job of maintaining dimensions than most formats, but I haven't used it in years. Stream

Comment: Pipe:  hadn't thought about Inkscape.  Good reminder.

Comment: Ignacio:  I've been doing toner transfer for a while using cheap eBay copper clad.  I tried MG Chemicals boards and my pcbs took a huge step forward.  I guess I've become a "fanboy" for them.

Comment: JMS:  I tried the method you outline above, but the image I got was VERY low res.  I viewed the image in PS Viewer and photoshop with the same results.  It seems like your image above is higher resolution, but in both your's and my image both have a pattern of lines in the background.  I can deal with that, but the resolution makes this unusable.  Is there a way to get a higher resolution image, or is there something about my system that might dictate the resolution?

Comment: Pipe:  I found that I don't know how to convert the image to strictly black and white in Inkscape, and then invert it.  The image comes in as an RGB from eagle, and inverting wont work for the RGB file.  Sheeze, I"m just a barrel of not-know-how today, aren't I?

Comment: @CharlieRC Eagle draws filled polygons as a bunch of lines when exporting as a vector graphics file (like ps, eps or pdf). In theory there is a slight overlap, but in practice it isn't enough and many programs still get confused when rendering such files and show artifacts which appear as dark lines (which disappear when you zoom in). Your printer should interpret the postscript file correctly and not print out the artifacts.

Comment: @CharlieRC I'm not sure what you mean by "very low res", as postscript in this case acts as a [vector graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) format and doesn't have a resolution in the traditional sense. In theory you could zoom in infinitely without any "pixelation" or blur. For example, [here](http://i.imgur.com/9xpi3Js.png) is the .ps output at 1x zoom (appearing low res), and [here is the same file zoomed in](http://i.imgur.com/6pZmyID.png) much further. Note how the dark bands and "low res" features disappear.

Comment: Ok then, I am dramatically missing something.  I see no way to "zoom in" in cam processing or even to view the output.  Select PS_INVERED and save to a .ps file. Then I open the file in PS VIEWER and what I see is not a vector graphic but a very low res roster graphic.  I would love to send you the output but I am not sure how to do that on StackExchange.

Comment: @CharlieRC I guarantee you that the file is just fine, you just need more appropriate software (Adobe Acrobat, GSWiev) or you can convert the file into PDF [with an online tool](https://online2pdf.com/convert-ps-to-pdf). I tried "PS Viewer" myself and I can confirm that zoom isn't implemented properly; the application renders the (vector) postcript data into a fixed resolution [raster image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics) at startup, and zooming in just scales the rendered raster image. The same applies to photoshop, as it has no native support for vector graphics.

Comment: Urika!   GSview worked.  Thank you very much.Now I am seeing a vector graphic and the artifacts are gone.  But following pattern:  another question.  I need to be able to print more than one copy of the board on a single sheet of tranparency.  Is that possible somehow with this software.